Safari browser shows the play button/does not autoplay for background video in Version 17.2.1
I had made a background video for my website which worked on all browsers. But there seems to be some kind of issue with Safari browser Version 17.2.1. By default that video will be stopped and the play button will be visible (Which is not the case for other browsers).
Please check out the below snippet (Please Open it in full page for better understanding):


#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
<!-- The video -->
<video aria-label="background-video" aria-hidden="true" preload="true" role="presentation" muted loop playsInline autoPlay id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://dl6.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>



I have given all the properties suggested by others in the community muted loop playsInline autoPlay but it does not seem to work for  Safari browser Version 17.2.1.
tldr; How can i fix the issue where background video will show the play button and remains paused (doesn't autoplay) at the beginning (only on Safari browsers)?
Edit : I just found out that this problem occurs only when the system is in Battery saver mode
If you have safari browser you can open this question (Run the code snippet) and compare it with either chrome or Firefox browsers.
There are other major websites that are facing this issue if someone needs the list i can provide them too? it's a major one

Works ok in Safari 17.4.1 on iPhone.

@James the issue is that some people might use Safari Version 17.2.1, So is there a way to overcome this discrepancy

I am facing the above problem too, is there any way that this can be fixed?

Which device/OS are you seeing this problem on?

@James MacOs, Chip:Apple M1

Hi @BigChungus, thanks for updating the issue cause as due to battery saver mode. Could you also please add it as an answer to this question? It would be easier for everyone to find the solution and to know that this question is fixed.

Another alternate cause could be if Autoplay permissions disabled in the browser.

This article suggests that a <div> where the background is set to a video file will autoplay in a loop in Safari, and that you can layer this on top of your <video> element to build a cross-browser solution.

Safari might have limitations when it comes to autoplaying media, especially when it comes to conserving battery life. Its Apple, you know how they can be, and Safari is one of the weirdest browsers I can find on the internet.
To ensure videos play correctly in Safari, you may need to integrate JavaScript to manage autoplay functionality. Here is a simple example of how this can be achieved:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
  
  // Check if the video can autoplay
  var promise = video.play();
  
  if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(function() {
      // Autoplay started successfully
      console.log('Autoplay started');
      // Hide play button and allow user interaction to start playback
      // video.controls = false;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Autoplay was prevented
      console.log('Autoplay was prevented:', error);

    });
  }
});
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
<!-- The video -->
<video aria-label="background-video" aria-hidden="true" preload="true" role="presentation" muted loop playsInline autoPlay id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://dl6.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>



If you want to hide the controls you can do that by setting the controls attribute to false on the video tag like this <video controls="false" ...>
or via javascript as i commented in the snippet above.
Also check the browser media autoplay permissions as @james-ashok mentioned in his comment.

Thank you for answering. The issue still persists in safari browser, But if its battery saver or not i wanted to play the video automatically. the safari shows the message saying Autoplay was prevented.

Some browsers dont autoplay media if the tab of the browser is not focused. maybe something to do with that?
if not, try removing all those attributes from the video tag and add them one by one.
a browser should not stop you from playing a video if it is muted normally.
otherwise, there is something different going on.
try different video format, updating the browser, checking if there is a plugin that is cousing the issue. or even if its a setting in the browser that someone or a tool has set in the background to block popups and such annoying things.
